# How does lambda in python 3 handle the argument reference?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm learning flask, and now I'm reading the flask code.
I come into a block that I can not understand completely.

```
def implements_to_string(cls):
    cls.__unicode__ = cls.__str__
    cls.__str__ = lambda x: x.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
    return cls

@implements_to_string
class Test(object):
    def __init__ (self):
        pass

test = Test()
print(test.__str__)
print(test.__str__())
```

The first print shows the lambda method as:

```
<bound method Test.<lambda> of <__main__.Test object at 0x7f98d70d1210>>
```

The second:

```
<__main__.Test object at 0x7fcc4394d210>
```

So when does the `x` in the lambda in func `implements_to_string` become the `cls` object?
Is it just an inner mechanism I just need to remember now?
Or is there something else behind need to know?

Comment: The `x` parameter when calling the lambda function is not the `Test` class but the instance `test`. Python invokes instancemethods with the instance (`self`) as first argument.

Comment: @resi Thank you very much. I under stand now that the lambda function under a class environment will take the first param as `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the `lambda` keyword. This function returns the sum of its two arguments: `lambda a, b: a+b`. Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required. They are syntactically restricted to a single expression. Semantically, they are just syntactic sugar for a normal function definition.

Your implementation of `implements_to_string` is similar to what I have here:

```
def implements_to_string(cls):
    cls.__unicode__ = cls.__str__

    def lambda_func(self):
        return self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')

    cls.__str__ = lambda_func
    return cls
```

---

> So when does the `x` in the lambda in func `implements_to_string` become the `cls` object?

When you use `print(test.__str__)` you are printing the method itself and its representation is printed.

But when you use `print(test.__str__())` you are first executing the function and printing what is returned by the method.

Comment: You may want to use the conventional `self` variable name instead of `x` in the included code snippet to make it even clearer what is going on.

Comment: I figure out now that the first param in lambda under class circumstance will be treated as `self` as in normal function. Thank you @AKS and @Martin.

Comment: I just used `x` to keep it closer to what the user have in the snippet.